# How to deal with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when doing encryption in java?

Tags: java, encryption

When I process a large volume of data during encryption its heap size becomes full and throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

I don't want to increase the java heap size manually in my container

Here is my java code

```
public String encrypt(String data) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I also heard to use cipher.update first then use cipher.doFinal but it won't work for me because i am dealing with only single block of data

What do I do so that my heap size does not affect?

I saw similar issue [Java Out of Memory Error during Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235427/java-out-of-memory-error-during-encryption)
but it won't resolve my problem

I also don't want to specify the maximum amount of bytes to proceed at time

Comment: You are probably processing large `data` input. Which you have at least 3 times in memory. A copy in `encrypted` and then an even larger `String` in `Base64.encodeBase64String`. Al that is in memory and will use up space.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CipherOutputStream:

```
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("ciphertext"), cipher);
```

Now write to the stream using any mechanism including Writer.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cos));
pw.println(data);
```

Don’t forget to close any streams when done.

Comment: I tried performance was improved but still runs out of memory