# Java Cipher Decryption on large files

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to decrypt files by Java and below codes work. However it will have `OutOfMemory` exception when decrypting large files. I tried to change to `cipher.update` but the program will freeze without any responding.

How can I change this from `doFinal` to `update`?

```
public File decryptDataFile(File inputFile, File outputFile, File keyFile, String correlationId) {
        
        try {
            
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            
            String key = new String(Files.readAllBytes(keyFile.toPath())).trim();
            
            byte[] byteInput = this.getFileInBytes(inputFile);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
            
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            System.arraycopy(byteInput, 8, salt, 0, 8);
            SecretKeyFactory fact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL", "BC");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, fact.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt, 100)));

            byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(byteInput, 16, byteInput.length-16);
            
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            os.write(data);
            os.close();
            
            if(outputFile.exists()) {
                return outputFile;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
            
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            logger.WriteLog(appConfig.getPlatform(), "INFO", alsConfig.getProjectCode(), correlationId, alsConfig.getFunctionId(), "SCAN_DECRYPT", e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " - " + e.getMessage() );
            return null;
        }

    }
```

My non-working version:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            
String key = new String(Files.readAllBytes(keyFile.toPath())).trim();
            
byte[] byteInput = this.getFileInBytes(inputFile);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
            
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
System.arraycopy(byteInput, 8, salt, 0, 8);
SecretKeyFactory fact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, fact.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt, 100)));
            
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            
int b;
byte[] d = new byte[8];
while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
   fos.write(d, 0, b);
}
fos.flush();
fos.close();
cis.close();
if(outputFile.exists()) {
    return outputFile;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You read the whole file in memory. You should use `CipherOutputStream` / `CipherInputStream`

Comment: Found an example in Baeldung but I cannot figure out how to implement in my codes. How can I use `CipherOutputStream` / `CipherInputStream` ?

Comment: Please provide the encryptDataFile-method as well as I'm not shure whats in the first 8 byte of data (Your'e reading the salt from pos 8 to 16 = 8 byte) of byteInput and use the rest as input for cipher.Update)

Comment: @MichaelFehr Thanks for reply. The encryption was done by this shell script actually. `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -salt -in ${tarFile} -out ${encTarFile} -pass file:./${KEY_RANDOM}`

Comment: comment: using your openssl-line I'm getting a respond that openssl is NOT using PBKDF2 as key derivation method: 
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
Could you please provide your decryptDataFile-method before you made modifications to decrypt the data? Does this method (I mean the unmodified one) has ever decrypted data sucessfully?

Comment: I changed the code in my question to original one. It is working fine until I meet a 1.7GB file.

Comment: You are still reading (and writing) the whole thing into memory in one piece. There are limits to how far that scales. Use streams.

Comment: May I know how I can switch to streams? I followed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235427/java-out-of-memory-error-during-encryption) to modify but I get padding exceptions.

Comment: I tried to use `CipherInputStream`. I did not encounter any error but the output .gz file is corrputed. ```cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, fact.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt, 100)));
   
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
   
   CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
   
   int b;
      byte[] d = new byte[8];
      while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
          fos.write(d, 0, b);
      }
      fos.flush();
      fos.close();
      cis.close();```

Comment: Please don't post longer code as a comment, but edit your question and add the code there. Did you separate the OpenSSL prefix (`Salted__`) and the salt from the `FileInputStream`? Also, your buffer is unreasonably small.

Comment: @Topaco: thanks for the information about the first 8 bytes of the encrypted data ("Salted__").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreword: I couldn't decrypt with your original method a file that was encrypted with your openssl-command

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -salt -in ${tarFile} -out ${encTarFile} -pass file:./${KEY_RANDOM}
```

but the following method should decode even large files similar to your original method - I tested files up to 1 GB size.

**Edit:** *Regarding the OpenSSL statement, it's worth mentioning that since v1.1.0 the default digest has changed from MD5 to SHA256,
so for higher versions the -md MD5 option must be set explicitly for compatibility with the Java code.* (thanks to @Topaco).

Please keep in mind that I don't care about correct file paths for

```
new FileInputStream(inputFile.toPath().toString())
and
new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toPath().toString())
```

as I'm working locally and with my folder, maybe you have to change the code to "find" your files. As well there is no exception handling in this example.

The code line

```
byte[] ibuf = new byte[8096];
```

is defining the buffer that is used - a larger buffer makes the decryption faster but consumes more memory (8096 means 8096 byte compared to 1 Gbyte when reading the complete file into memory and causing the out of memory error).

```
public static File decryptDataFileBuffered(File inputFile, File outputFile, File keyFile, String correlationId) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String key = new String(Files.readAllBytes(keyFile.toPath())).trim();
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        byte[] salted = new byte[8]; // text SALTED__
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile.toPath().toString()); // i don't care about the path as all is lokal
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toPath().toString())) // i don't care about the path as all is lokal
        {
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[8096]; // thats the buffer used - larger is faster
            int len;
            in.read(salted);
            in.read(salt);
            SecretKeyFactory fact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL", "BC");
            SecretKey secretKey = fact.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt, 100));
            System.out.println("secretKey length: " + secretKey.getEncoded().length + " data: " + bytesToHex(secretKey.getEncoded()));
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = cipher.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if (obuf != null)
                    out.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = cipher.doFinal();
            if (obuf != null)
                out.write(obuf);
         } catch (IOException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            return outputFile;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Edit2:** As commented by @Topaco the usage of CipherInput/OutputStream shortens the code and makes it better readable, so here is the code:

```
public static File decryptDataFileBufferedCipherInputStream (File inputFile, File outputFile, File keyFile, String correlationId) throws
            IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String key = new String(Files.readAllBytes(keyFile.toPath())).trim();
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        byte[] salted = new byte[8]; // text SALTED__
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile.toPath().toString()); // i don't care about the path as all is lokal
             CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toPath().toString())) // i don't care about the path as all is lokal
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            in.read(salted);
            in.read(salt);
            SecretKeyFactory fact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL", "BC");
            SecretKey secretKey = fact.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt, 100));
            System.out.println("secretKey length: " + secretKey.getEncoded().length + " data: " + bytesToHex(secretKey.getEncoded()));
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            int nread;
            while ((nread = cipherInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, nread);
            }
            out.flush();
        }
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            return outputFile;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I tried to implement on my own but the file I decrypted is corrupted. I put my non-working version here. May I know which part goes wrong?

Comment: Works fine. The last part could be implemented a bit more compact with `CipherInputStream`. The iteration number (here 100) is ignored, because implicitly 1 is used. Regarding the OpenSSL statement, it's worth mentioning that since v1.1.0 the default digest has changed from MD5 to SHA256, so for higher versions the `-md MD5` option must be set explicitly for compatibility with the Java code.

Comment: @Felix Wong: "your non-working-version" still reads the complete "inputFile" to "byteInput" and in the stream-part it is not reading the first 2 * 8 bytes "header" so the CipherInputStream is trying to decrypt it as well - see my version in Edit2.